# How to hold textbox during browser scrolling and resize

Tags: css, jsp, textbox

I just don't know what else to do. Need someone's help please. I have a textbox, which should be relative to the content id. However, when I run and try to scroll in the browser window, the box is fixed to the browser window and not moving even when I scroll. It should fix to the img id that I have set. The image is moving but the textbox is not. How can I fix this?

This is basically the code that I use.

**singledose.jsp**

```
<form method="GET" action="SingleDose" id="searchform">
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header2">
            <h2>Single Dose Model</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <div id="picture">
                <div id="img">
                    <img alt="PK Diagram" src="PKdiagram1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="parameter">
                    <input type="text" name="ka_Central" class="ka_Central"
                        id="ka_Central" value="<%=ka_Central%>" /> <input type="text"
                        name="k12" class="k12" id="k12" value="<%=k12%>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="webfigure">
                <jsp:include page="dose.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**dosestyle.css**

```
img {
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    height: 275px;
    position: relative;
    top: 69px;
    width: 550px;
}
#container {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header2 {
    background-color: #66CCFF;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    padding: 0px;
}
#parameter {
    width: 70%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 82px;
    float: left;
}
.ka_Central {
    background-color: #FFFF88;
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    width: 50px;
    text-indent: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.k12 {
    background-color: #FFFF88;
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 315px;
    left: 385px;
}
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: `position:fixed` positions the element relatively to the browser window, you probably shouldn't use it in this case.

Comment: @NicoFerna. I have tried. But it is still moving when I resize and scroll the browser window. Actually the textbox is located overlapped with image. The image is fixed but the textbox is not. That is why I put it relative to the content. What else I can do?

Comment: @NicoFerna, I have updated the question. Actually, what I wrote before was wrong. I confuse myself too. So sorry. Basically, what I need is the textbox to stick at the image and when I scroll the browser window, it will move. The position:fixed will only make it stay relative to the browser window. Hope you may help. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to get it. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not a programmer and just a newbies. Please don't expect a very technical programming answer. This is just to share what I did.

I have actually tried to search for the answer everywhere but all the same issues found were not being answered. Basically, this was what I did. Very simple. I just deleted the #parameter function and change all the textboxes position to `position: relative`.

The same problem like others, we forgot to take out the `position` format from the `parent element` (in this case #parameter). I think that 1 job could only be done by 1 element, either the children or the parent itself. Or there may be some other way that does not come to my mind. I have made trial and error on other parts, and it works the same. Once I deleted the position format from the `parent element`, tadaaaa!!! Done..  ;)